# How to set a maximum distance between points for interpolation when using scipy.interpolate.griddata?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have a spatial set of data with Z values I want to interpolate using some matplotlib or scipy module. My XY points have a concave shape and I don't want interpolated values in the empty zone. Is there a method that easily allow user to set a maximum distance between points to avoid interpolation in the empty zone?

Comment: I also had a similar question. The method suggested earlier works like a charm. However, if linear interpolation is not absolutely needed, you can choose "nearest" interpolation and easily avoid the gaps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I struggled with the same question and found a work around by re-using the kd-tree implementation that scipy itself uses for the nearest neighbour interpolation, masking the interpolated result array with the result of the kd-tree querying result.

Consider the example code below:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some random data
xy = np.random.random((2**15, 2))
z = np.sin(10*xy[:,0]) * np.cos(10*xy[:,1])

grid = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(0, 1, 512),
    np.linspace(0, 1, 512)
)

# Interpolate
result1 = scipy.interpolate.griddata(xy, z, tuple(grid), 'linear')

# Show
plt.figimage(result1)
plt.show()

# Remove rectangular window
mask = np.logical_and.reduce((xy[:,0] > 0.2, xy[:,0] < 0.8, xy[:,1] > 0.2, xy[:,1] < 0.8))
xy, z = xy[~mask], z[~mask]

# Interpolate
result2 = scipy.interpolate.griddata(xy, z, tuple(grid), 'linear')

# Show
plt.figimage(result2)
plt.show()
```

This generates the following two images. Notices the strong interpolation artefacts because of the missing rectangle window in the centre of the data.

[image: original data] [image: missing data]

Now if we run the code below on the same example data, the following image is obtained.

```
THRESHOLD = 0.01

from scipy.interpolate.interpnd import _ndim_coords_from_arrays
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

# Construct kd-tree, functionality copied from scipy.interpolate
tree = cKDTree(xy)
xi = _ndim_coords_from_arrays(tuple(grid), ndim=xy.shape[1])
dists, indexes = tree.query(xi)

# Copy original result but mask missing values with NaNs
result3 = result2[:]
result3[dists > THRESHOLD] = np.nan

# Show
plt.figimage(result3)
plt.show()
```

[image: masked result]

I realize it may not be the visual effect you're after exactly. Especially if your dataset is not very dense you'll need to have a high distance threshold value in order for legitimately interpolated data not to be masked. If your data is dense enough, you might be able to get away with a relatively small radius, or maybe come up with a smarter cut-off function. Hope that helps.

Comment: In order to run the second part of your code, I needed to replace:  `xi = _ndim_coords_from_arrays(tuple(grid), ndim=xy.shape[1])`  with:  `xi = _ndim_coords_from_arrays(tuple(grid))`